# Vue Firebase firebase/auth not working but firebase/firestore works fine. "auth is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, authentication

any idea why my { auth } functions "are not functions" but my { db } functions work just fine? Example files below.

The error I get when trying to call login() method is

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.auth.auth is not a function"
```

Using Vue 2 and installed firebase with npm install firebase --save.

**src/firebase.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'xx',
  authDomain: 'xx',
  databaseURL: 'xx',
  projectId: 'xx',
  storageBucket: 'xx',
  messagingSenderId: 'xx',
  appId: 'xx',
  measurementId: 'xx',
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

**login.vue**

```
import { auth } from '@/firebase';
login() {
  try {
      auth
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(() => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
},
```

**Example code from documentation, works just fine**

```
import { db } from '@/firebase';
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
export { db, auth };
```

you should not do

```
login() {
  try {
      auth
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        ...
```

but

```
login() {
  try {
      auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        ...
```

---

Firestore works fine because you correctly do `db.collection("cities").doc("SF");` and not `db.firestore().collection("cities").doc("SF");`.

Comment: Jesus I spent like two hours on this and didn't notice that. I'll get back on it later today and when it's done I'll mark this solved :) Thanks!